# Couldn't find the record react node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am a beginner of react and node js. I am search the record using node js as a backend react as a front end. I am search the record by name. If I enter the correct name relevant records will be displayed on the below textfield but when I enter the name and click search button I checked through the console I noticed that I had the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

I have checked through the postman it is working perfectly well this is the api of I checked **http://localhost:4000/user/findOne/Kish**

What I tried so far I attached below:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
 
function StudentCrud() {

const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
const [phone, setPhone] = useState([]);


  async function search(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user/findOne/", + name 
        
       
        ).then((res) => 
        {
         console.log(res.data);
    
         if (res.data =='User not found') 
         {
           alert("User not found");
         } 
         else 
         { 
          alert("User found");
            
         } 
         
      }, fail => {
       console.error(fail); // Error!
});
    }


     catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  
  }


    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Student Details</h1>
      <div class="container mt-4">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Student Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="name"
              value={name}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setName(event.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4" onClick={search}>
              Search
          </button>
          </form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="address"
              value={address}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setAddress(event.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="phone"
              value={phone}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setPhone(event.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </div>
          

        

       
      
      </div>
      </div>
   );
            }
  
  export default StudentCrud;
```

Comment: `axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user/findOne/", + name )` Are you sure this code compiles? not `axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user/findOne/" + name )`

Comment: now it is working thanks but the result i need to pass the textfields below. i wrote this way  setAddress(res.data.address);
          setPhone(res.data.phone);    but not working can you correct it

Comment: Sorry, I just tested it and it does compile. Are your code and errors still the same as described in the title? If it is a 404 error code, it means that the request URL is wrong, not a problem with passing parameters. You should try to modify the code to what I just suggested, just because it compiles doesn't mean it works.

Comment: yes working now .{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "_id": "64086296c577a564f938ec4e",
        "name": "Kish",
        "address": "Muthuusd",
        "phone": "6546456",
        "__v": 0
    }
}

Comment: this data i recevied on console log. have call it on textfield  i wrote like this setAddress(res.data.address);  but not working

Comment: You should update the question with what you just said, the code, the error, and the response data you were hoping to get, and what you're getting now.

Comment: undefined   i got the respone if i type like this consol.log(res.data.address);